# Converting two empirical equations with one independent variable into one empirical equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a physical problem that calls out for the help of mathematicians. I would like to measure the state of charge (SOC) value of NiMH batteries. The SOC value is strongly dependent on the open circuit voltage (OCV) and the temperature. I can measure both, the OCV and the temperature and I have empirically determined graphs for SOC as a function of temperature and as a function of voltage. I would like to come up with an empirical formula for SOC(OCV,temperature). Please have a look at the graphs below for the dependencies:
https://ibb.co/TTvzSJy
https://ibb.co/vX1wd64

Best and thank you!

Marco

Comment: Have a look at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327617458_A_Study_on_the_Open_Circuit_Voltage_and_State_of_Charge_Characterization_of_High_Capacity_Lithium-Ion_Battery_Under_Different_Temperature/link/5b99c4eca6fdcc59bf8def54/download

Comment: What do you mean by *empirical formula?*

Comment: I have digitized the datasheet of the battery, i.e. the Capacity vs voltage and the capacity vs temperature diagrams and I would like to have a capacity vs voltage and temperature equation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the publication is interesting but doesn't give an expression for the State of charge as a function of voltage AND temperature. It provides fitting parameters for state of charge vs voltage for different temperatures.